# Show only two rows and show ellipse if truncated

Tags: css

I have a `<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>` that contains a string in which can wrap to more than 2 rows, I want to only show two rows, and here's what I've done:

```
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.3em;
min-height: 2.6em;
max-height: 2.6em;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

The only problem is, ellipsis will only show if my text looks like:

```
pharetra
adipiscing
```

Into

```
pharetra
adipi...
```

But it won't work if my text looks like:

```
Sed
ipsum
risus
```

Actual result:

```
Sed
ipsum
```

What I want:

```
Sed
ipsum...
```

Here's the html snippet:

```
<button class="foo" title="bar">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64," height="40" width="40" style="background-color: rgb(57, 153, 198);">
    <div style="width: 70.26px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.3em; min-height: 2.6em; max-height: 2.6em;
text-overflow: ellipsis;">Some text to be truncated</div>
</button>
```

Comment: You mean ellipsis...

Comment: Can you show the html you are applying this to? `.li` perhaps?

Comment: @Psi you are in deed correct!

Comment: This is impossible using CSS only.

Comment: You have enough reputation to know how to ask a question on this site. What is CSS if there isn't any HTML attached?